# Обработка событий Button в Android

Tags: android, java

В приложении есть необходимость обрабатывать два события:
 - кнопка нажата (*onClick()*) 
 - кнопка отпущена

Описание первого события мне понятно, но как описать второе?

Comment: если надо менять стиль кнопки при этом, то вариант бармалея не самый правильный

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ловите `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP`, примерно так:

```
button.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
             Log.i(TAG, "Кнопка отпущена!");
        }
    }
};
```